# Checking the style of child nodes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a search utility where each section has a `<h1>` tag title. 
Within each section, there is a span that I search through with a filter and either display them or not. The issue I'm running into is I'm not sure how to target the `<h1>` tag within the wrapper and display it as well.

I was considering having another script looking at the elements and check if the children have the display none styling or not, although this seems like a barbaric approach.

Here's a small example. If you search the number the list filter's as it should and the title is still there of course. It's that `<h1>` tag I want to hide if the list in that section is 'empty' or hidden. Any suggestions?

Could I do something where I grab the parentNode of the parentNode and check the styling?

or prehaps grab the list's (list1,list2,list3) and on filter search also check if their childNodes are being displayed?

```js
 function search() {
  var input, filter, content, txtValue,list;
  input = document.getElementById("search-input");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  list = document.getElementById("search-list");
  content = list.getElementsByTagName("span");
  for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
   if (content) {
    txtValue = content[i].innerHTML;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
     content[i].parentNode.style.display = "";
    } else {
     content[i].parentNode.style.display = "none";
    }
   }       
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search for numbers" onkeyup="search()">
  <div id="search-list">
    <div class="list1">
      <h1> List 1</h1>
      <button><span>one</span></button>
      <button><span>two</span></button>
      <button><span>three</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="list2">
      <h1> List 2</h1>
      <button><span>four</span></button>
      <button><span>five</span></button>
      <button><span>six</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="list3">
      <h1> List 3</h1>
      <button><span>seven</span></button>
      <button><span>eight</span></button>
      <button><span>nine</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
content[index]
```

returns a span element.

One level up in the hierarchy is it's parent - the **button**.

Another level up is the button's parent - which is the **div**.

From there the **h1** tag is the next children of the div, so to access it you can use

```
content[index].parentNode.parentNode.children[0]
```